# Clean Document Recovery after Kill Microsoft word/powerpoint

Tags: ms-word, ms-office, office-2013

When I open document and make change on document without save, then I kill the process(word), even if the file also been deleted, when open again win word I get the Document recovery form.

How I can clean this Document Recovery so after kill Word and delete file I will not see it?

Thanks,
Joseph

Answer (score 0):

I find that I can remove the registry key(s) from:

HKEY_USERS(SID)\Software\Microsoft\Office\1**x**.0**Word**\Resiliency\DocumentRecovery

**x**: 4 / 5 acording to office version.

Instead of **Word**, can also be Excel or Powerpoint...